# Camera in windows phone 8.1 app is crashing

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have an app with home page and camera page.
when I go to page with camera it starts and all is working fine.
I can go back to home page using device back button and go again to camera page and it still is OK. I also have code to switch off the camera when phone goes to sleep or app change its visibility status and it also works OK (stops the camera when e.Visible is false and starts it when e.Visible is true).

The problem occurs when those events are in this sequence (and maybe other sequences too but I didn't test it fully)

```
1. go to page with camera
2. go back to home page
3. go to page with camera again
4. app lose visibility
5. app is visible again --> crash
```

below is the code for events:

```
    void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (!e.Handled && Frame.CurrentSourcePageType.FullName == "MyApp.CamPage")
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            StopCamera();
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(Elements));
        }
    }

    private void Current_VisibilityChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.VisibilityChangedEventArgs e)
    {                     
        if (Frame.CurrentSourcePageType.FullName == "MyApp.CamPage")
        {
            if (e.Visible)
            {
                StartCamera();
            }
            else
            {
                StopCamera();
            }
        }
    }

    private async void StartCamera()
    {

        if (mediaCapture == null)
        {
            // start camera 
            mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

            DeviceInformation _deviceInformation = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture)).FirstOrDefault(d => d.EnclosureLocation != null && d.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

            var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
            if (_deviceInformation != null)
                settings.VideoDeviceId = _deviceInformation.Id;

            await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

            // rotate to see preview vertically
            mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);

            captureElement.Source = mediaCapture;
            await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
        }          
    }

    private async void StopCamera()
    {
        if (mediaCapture != null)
        {
            await mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
            captureElement.Source = null;
            mediaCapture = null;
        }
    }
```

when I debug the code I've noticed that in the scenario mentioned above when app is changing its visibility to true it goes to Current_VisibilityChanged method TWICE and crash happens at the second time when camera is attempting to start.

Most important for me is how should my code look like to aid the situation?
But also its interesting why is it going to that method twice when in both cases e.Visible and e.Handled has the same value?
Why is it working fine when the sequence is as follows:

1. go to page with camera
2. app lose visibility
3. app is visible again --> all OK

Comment: at which line does it crash?

Comment: Where do you subscribe to *VisibilityChanged*? Aren't you subscribing twice and thus it's called twice, the second time throwing exception?

Comment: Why don't you use the OnNavigatedTo() and OnNavigatedFrom() events to initialize and release the camera?

Comment: I am subscribing only once to that method Romasz

Comment: First time it goes as far as DeviceInformation _deviceInformation = ...
and kind of jumps out from that method... second time it is crashing at following line: await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

Comment: I am starting camera in OnNavigatedTo(), I've never seen OnNavigatedFrom() so I guess thats the reason I didn't use it. I am quite new to Windws Phone apps. Maybe you can share an example how it suppose to look like in your opinion Jogy?

Comment: Introducing code below helped the situation, thank you all for help...

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            StopCamera();
        }